# implement Multiset using HashSet

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I have to implement a multiset. I have used a hashset and inside my class I have made an inner class of objects with as instance variables one of type E generic and one of type int to count the occurrences. I have an add method that needs to add an object within the multiset. Practically by invoking the internal class constructor every time it overwrites the object. He does not put more than one in my container. How is it possible?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0WnM.png)

```
public int add(E element, int occurrences) {
    // TODO Implementare
    int b=0;
    if (element==null) throw new NullPointerException();
    if (occurrences<0 || occurrences ==Integer.MAX_VALUE) throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    boolean g=false;
    for (Element x: contenitore) {
        if (x.getElement().equals(element)) {
            x.setOccorrenze(occurrences);

         b=x.getOccorrenze()-occurrences;
        }}

            this.contenitore.add(new  Element(element,occurrences));
            b=0;


    return b;   
    }


public class MyMultiset<E> implements Multiset<E> {
// TODO Inserire le variabili istanza che servono

 private Set<Element> contenitore;

// TODO Inserire eventuali classi interne per gli elementi del multinsieme e
// per l'iteratore.
```

class Element {

```
private  E valore;
    private  int occorrenze;



    public Element( E valore, int occorrenze) {
        this.valore=valore;


enter code here

    this.occorrenze=occorrenze;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return valore;
    }
    public int getOccorrenze() {
        return occorrenze;


enter code here

}
    public void setOccorrenze(int v) {
        occorrenze+=v;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: Please post the code directly in the question (you can edit the question), not as a comment.